1990's movie\miniseries about a TV superhero transferred to another dimension
This was a cheesy made for TV movie or mini series that was about an actor who plays a superhero on television. He and the actor who plays his sidekick on the show get transferred into another dimension and have to actually be the characters they play on TV. They get out of the final fight with the villain by saying a chocolate drink's name backwards that advertises on the show.  
Does anyone have any idea what this is? It's from my childhood and it's driving me crazy that I cant find anything about it online. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks! 

This isn't the answer to your question, but it is a very similar concept to the 1999 film, Galaxy Quest. (In which a TV Sci-Fi space-ship crew are abducted by aliens who've recreated their on-screen environment perfectly, but made it work).

The Adventures of Captain Zoom in Outer Space from 1995 (with Ron Perlman as the villain).

The forces of evil are attempting to recapture a human-inhabited Earth-like planet that has been liberated by rebels. The son of one of the rebel leaders, an electronic genius, searches the galaxy for a hero and finds Captain Zoom, star of a 1950s TV series. He is transported to the planet as its savior, which role he must play despite himself.

The cheesy Captain Zoom and his sidekick advertize a chocolate drink on their show with the slogan "Chocko Socko is Boffo"; later on, at a key point on the alien planet, Captain Zoom recites the slogan backwards to open the doors to a temple. Here's the trailer:



